How to interpret values of a Guided Backpropagation saliency map?
I would like to know what negative, positive and close to zero values of a Guided Backpropagation saliency map mean. The method was introduced in this paper.
I thought that high values mean that this pixel of the input image has a high influence to the output.
I am generating the Guided Backpropagation saliency map for the last layer (before softmax). This is the Tensorflow code I'm using:
@tf.custom_gradient
def guidedRelu(x):
  def grad(dy):
    return tf.cast(dy>0, "float32") * tf.cast(x>0, "float32") * dy
  return tf.nn.relu(x), grad

gb_model = Model(
    inputs = model.inputs,
    outputs = [model.get_layer("classifier").output] # layer before softmax
)
layer_dict = [layer for layer in gb_model.layers[1:] if hasattr(layer,'activation')]
for layer in layer_dict:
    if layer.activation == tf.keras.activations.relu:
        layer.activation = guidedRelu

with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    inputs = tf.cast(input_img, tf.float32)
    tape.watch(inputs)
    outputs = gb_model(inputs)

grads = tape.gradient(outputs, inputs)[0]

The result looks like this (its postprocessed a bit):

However, when I look at a pixel and change it's brightness e.g. in the red channel by +50, the saliency value (of the red channel) at that same pixel does not seem to give any hint on what will happen to the output of my model. So what exactly do the GB values mean?
In the image above you can see the saliency value of a pixel for the red channel (x axis) and what happens to the models output if I increase the brightness of that pixel in the red channel by 50 (y axis). I was expecting that for pixels with positive saliency values there would be a positive change for the output class (and for saliency values close to zero almost no change in the output class). I could observe this expected behaviour for the Vanialla Gradient method but not here.
So please tell me what the meaning of positive/negative/close to zero saliency values are.
Thanks in advance.
